# How can I find a transfer function between two signals in python?

Tags: python, transfer-function, array-signal-processing

If we call one signal $x$ and the other signal $y$.

I want to find a transfer function that takes $x$ as input and gives $y$ as output. I have recorded data of signal $x$ and $y$.
$$x(t) \overset{H}\rightarrow y(t)$$
$H(\omega)$ is the transfer function I want to find using Python.

Comment: It x is spectrally rich across your bandwidth of interest and your channel is linear, you can use the Wiener-Hopf equations for a least squares solution. I have another post here that demonstrates this. If x ie a narrow band tone, then the only thing you can determine is the phase and magnitude response for that tone.

Comment: What is your input signal (i.e $x$) ? How noisy is the input? how noisy is the output?

Comment: My input signal corresponds to to acceleration of a structure in one direction and the output signal corresponds to the acceleration of the same structure in a different direction

Comment: If you know the two signals (input and output) you could possibly do a (naive) deconvolution in the frequency domain. This would be a division of corresponding transforms $H \left( \omega \right) = \frac{Y \left( \omega \right)}{X \left( \omega \right)}$. Of course your system must be linear for this to hold (plus other numerical issues if you are implementing it in a digital machine).

Comment: @ZaellixA and importantly as I commented the transmitted waveform must be distributed across the channel bandwidth (ideally uniformly) as we can only solve for the deconvolution where spectral energy exists

Comment: Exactly, this is part of the numerical issues that I mentioned in my comment. Thanks for the clarification @DanBoschen

Comment: "My input signal corresponds to to acceleration of a structure in one direction and the output signal corresponds to the acceleration of the same structure in a different direction."  That doesn't sound like a candidate for a transfer function, unless your $x(t)$ is truly the input and sole cause of $y(t)$.  If they're both the result of something else, then you can find a correlation, but it's not a _transfer function_.  If $x(t)$ is _causing_ $y(t)$, then **edit your question** with this fact.

Comment: If $x(t)$ really does cause $y(t)$, then this is a problem in [system identification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_identification), which is going to go beyond a reasonable-length answer here.  We can make _specific suggestions_ about how to go about it, but only with a lot more detail.